# What is the probability of seeing $7$ heads in the toss of $12$ coins?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, self-learning

**Problem:** What is the probability of seeing $7$ heads in the toss of $12$ coins?

**My answer:** If $C(n,k)$ is the number of combinations of $k$ things taken $n$ at a time, then, since order does not matter, the number of successful outcomes is

$$
C(12,7)
$$

while the number of total outcomes is $2^{12}$.  Hence the probability is the quotient

$$
\frac{C(12,7)}{2^{12}}.
$$

**Book answer:** $\displaystyle \frac{C(12,5)}{2^{12}}.$

**Question:** Typo?

**Book:** "Methods of Mathematics" by Hamming

Comment: $\binom{12}{7} = \binom{12}{12-7} = \binom{12}{5}$.

Comment: Those two binomial coefficients are equal.

Comment: To expand a bit, just think of the fact that an event of observing 7 heads in 12 tosses is equivalent to the event of seeing 5 tails in 12 tosses, because each toss’ outcome possibilities (heads/tails) are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive.

Comment: Exactly seven, or at least seven? If J get eight heads, I still can see seven...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I interpreted it as exact.  But to your point I find this irritating about these problems in probability and counting sometimes.  Your answer is 'wrong' but correct for your interpretation of it.  They don't care (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a typo.  Your answer and the book answer evaluate to the same number, $\frac{99}{512} = 0.193359375$.  This follows from the identity ${n \choose k} = {n \choose {n-k}}$.

This can be easily seen by rephrasing the question as “What is the probability of seeing **5 tails** in the toss of 12 coins?”

Comment: I see it now.  I had forgotten about this identity and interpretation.  Hamming, the author, says "What you take is uniquely defined by what you leave" which I think is a pretty cool way to say it.

Answer (score 1):

You can break it up into more fundamental concepts as well. There are $2^{12}=4096$ possible flip outcomes. The flip outcomes of interest have the form TTTTTHHHHHHH.

There are $12!$ ways of arranging 12 distinct objects. If they aren't distinct, you need to divide by the number of ways to rearrange the identical items. Since there are  7 heads and 5 tails the result is $\frac{12!}{5!7!}= C(12,7)=C(12,5)$

So $C(12,7)/2^{12}$ is the answer, but the formula follows form more basic arguments.